# How to call another activity after destroy() of service is called

Tags: android, android-service

In this code I have created a service.After 3 seconds i want to destory this service and want to call another activity in destroy method.but this doesnt seem to work.

```
public class TimerService extends Service 
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId)
    {      
        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) 
        { 
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {

            }
            public void onFinish()
            {

                stopSelf();
            }
        }.start();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Dummy.class);
        i.putExtra("SessionTimedOut","Expire");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplication().startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Activity which calls My Service

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,TimerService.class);
        startService(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a notification that start the activity you want

Comment: _"... but this doesnt seem to work"_ -- Please be more specific. What behavior are you seeing? Is there something in logcat to indicate a problem?

Comment: control is not transfered to the mentioned "Dummy,class" and as a result no intent is also sent

Comment: tried your code as-it-is and it started Dummy.class (Activity). Have you added all your activities and service in AndroidManifest.xml and also show how you are STARTING your service? I used below code to start the service `startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));`

Comment: Thanks for the help.. This is how I am calling  
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,TimeService.class);
        startService(i);
    }

Comment: You should update your post with Answer so that others can know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert the code to the finish method:

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId)
{      
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Dummy.class);
            i.putExtra("SessionTimedOut","Expire");
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
            stopSelf();
        }
    }, 3000);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}
```

Comment: Who talking about the onFinish() of the service? I talked about that of the CountDownTimer

Comment: try to remove getApplication()

Comment: What not worked? the activity didn't start? try to open Dammy from the first Activity maybe the problem is elsewhere

Comment: control now immediately goes to Dummy . without waiting for the counter. my requirement is it should wait for 3 seconds and then go to Dummy

Comment: @yshahak...thanks a lot ...this code works flawlessly :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. I will be glad also id you will accept my answer (: